Magneto2.4.7 -p3 Click Admin Stores Configuration shows console errors
legacy-build.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeClassName is not a function
legacy-build.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeClassName is not a function
legacy-build.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeClassName is not a function
legacy-build.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeClassName is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeClassName is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeClassName is not a function
legacy-build.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: ah.attachEvent is not a function
legacy-build.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: ah.attachEvent is not a function
legacy-build.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: ah.attachEvent is not a function
legacy-build.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: ah.dispatchEvent is not a function
legacy-build.min.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
VM9971 theme.js:629 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).filter(...).collapse is not a function

Same error here; any idea?
